# How do I convert this Dax code into M language for comparing 2 dates

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

The goal is to categories table 1 with the the dates of  table 2 by whichever date is next in table 2. How can this be achieved in power query? I have provided the Dax script below.

Table 1: model with version

| Model | Version Number |
| --- | --- |
| EI1 | 17/01/2023 |
| EI1 | 19/01/2023 |
| EI1 | 28/01/2023 |
| EI1 | 02/02/2023 |
| EI2 | 05/02/2023 |
| EI2 | 26/02/2023 |
| EI2 | 04/03/2023 |
| EI2 | 08/03/2023 |

Table 2: Dates

| Date |
| --- |
| 13/01/23 |
| 27/01/23 |
| 10/02/23 |
| 24/02/23 |
| 07/03/23 |
| 21/03/23 |
| 05/04/23 |

For example

Table 3: model with version categorized

| Model | Version Number | Version category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EI1 | 17/01/2023 | 27/01/23 |
| EI1 | 19/01/2023 | 27/01/23 |
| EI1 | 28/01/2023 | 10/02/23 |
| EI1 | 02/02/2023 | 10/02/23 |
| EI2 | 05/02/2023 | 10/02/23 |
| EI2 | 26/02/2023 | 07/03/23 |
| EI2 | 04/03/2023 | 07/03/23 |

etc.

Below is the Code that works how can I write it in power query. Table1 and Table2 are distinct.

```
    DateAg = 

CALCULATE ( 
    MIN ( 'Date'[DateList]),
    FILTER ( 
        'Date',
        'Date'[DateList] >= 'EI'[Version]
    )
)
```

Comment: Please mark your old questions as solved and clarify your requirement. Presumably, you mean next date rather than closest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

Add a custom column:

```
(x)=> List.First(
 List.Select( Table2[Date], (y)=> y > x[Version Number]))
```

[image]

[image]